# Tunning up Activity with dialog theme

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I need to launch a Dialog from home screen widget, so I created an Activity with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

The problem is, that I would like make it look like standard dialog window ( buttons on the gray background, font and text size, paddings etc), like here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [android.com](http://developer.android.com/images/dialog_buttons.png))</sub>

This is how my "dialog" Activity looks like:

[image]

Is there some standard way (theme?) to make it look like standard system dialogs? Or do I have to imitate it in my own layout?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the same look for the buttons below by using the weight attribute and the framework drawable for the background behind them.  Hope this helps!

```
             <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
               android:orientation="horizontal">
               <Button
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"/>
               <Button
                android:text="Ok"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:id="@+id/okButton"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"/>
           </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The top dialog is built using the [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html), to create a simple dialog you should use that class.

Comment: I can't. This dialog is launched after pressing home screen widget button. I have to use PendingIntent to launch it.